# Clarification of a sentence from a video game, 「~為」

Tags: translation, meaning

As far as I understand, it generally says that the *Area server did not respond in a certain amount of time*.

Can anyone give me some insight as to how accurate my understanding of this message from the game is?

[image: japanese image from game]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 一定時間{いっていじかん}操作{そうさ}が行{おこな}われていない為{ため}
>   エリアサーバーへの接続{せつぞく}を切断{せつだん}しました。

The connection to the area server was terminated due to inactivity **or** *because no activity was recorded in the predetermined time.*

- 一定時間{いっていじかん} **timeout** or *predetermined time*.
- 操作{そうさ} activity or operation.
- 接続{せつぞく} **connection** as in connection to the server.
- 切断{せつだん} **disconnection** in this context.
- 為{ため} **due to** or *because of*.